# run python script with arguments on a remote linux host

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I have this python script that I'm trying to run on a remote host. However, the script requires two arguments. For example,
python script.py --port 4000 --service status

Now when I run the script locally on the machine it works fine. How can I run this same script on a remote linux machine. 
I've tried ssh user@remotehost python script.py --port 4000 --service status
This doesn't work. The arguments are not passed in.

Thank you

Comment: `sss user@foo 'put remote command in quotes'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following -

```
ssh user@remotehost "python script.py --port 4000 --service status"
```

Please notice the `"` double quotes, it has to be double quotes.

Comment: What version of ssh are you using? I can use single quotes. `ssh -V -> OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`